# Android: download XML and store to SD card

Tags: java, android, xml

I've got a method that is called in the onCreate method of my MainActivity. When I call that method I would expect an XML file to be stored on the SD card, but it doesn't appear to exist and the console doesn't seem to help much. The code for the method is listed below.

```
package com.example.inftimetable;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Environment;



public class DownloadXML {

    public static void downloadXML(){
        try {

            //set the download URL, a url that points to a file on the internet
            //this is the file to be downloaded
            URL url = new URL("http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml");

            //create the new connection
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            //and connect!
            urlConnection.connect();

            //set the path where we want to save the file
            //in this case, going to save it on the root directory of the
            //sd card.
            File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            //create a new file, specifying the path, and the filename
            //which we want to save the file as.
            File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"data.xml");

            //this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file we created
            FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

            //this will be used in reading the data from the internet
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            //this is the total size of the file
            int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();


            //variable to store total downloaded bytes
            int downloadedSize = 0;

            //create a buffer...
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer

            //now, read through the input buffer and write the contents to the file
            while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                    //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card
                    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                    //add up the size so we know how much is downloaded
                    downloadedSize += bufferLength;

            }
            //close the output stream when done
            fileOutput.close();
            //catch some possible errors...
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

}
```

and the class that calls the above method

```
package com.example.inftimetable;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            DownloadXML.downloadXML();


        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_search);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        }


}
```

Comment: How do you call this static function in your activity?
Have you debug this or Log something to see what happened?

Comment: I'll add the code, but the method is definitely being called and executed because I've had the console print statements at various points in the method above.

Comment: Did you add the permission to write to the SD card in your manifest?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Yeah I have included <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> in my manifest

Comment: So it's weird. Try to debug the function to see if it passes the download, check if there is internet connection on your device/emulator...

Comment: I've got an internet connection on the emulator, I've placed System.out.println just after fileOutput.close() and it successfully prints to LogCat

Comment: Solved my problem, I was searching in the wrong directory in DDMS for the file! Feel a bit stupid now!

Answer (score 0):

The code wrks correctly, I was looking in the wrong directory in DDMS